# some bytes have been replaced with the unicode substitution character while loading file

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

I have downloaded the source code of spring.Net from Github. When I open cs file of project, I saw the prompts 'some bytes have been replaced with the unicode substitution character while loading file XXX.cs with Chinese Simplified(GB2312) encoding. Saving the file will not preserve the original file contents' like this picture 
[image]

I don't want to save all the file one by one, how can I deal with this problem?

Comment: Can you show your code for the saving??

Comment: Either convert all files to utf8 before loading them, or use AppLocale to run VS with the same legacy encoding the original author used. Perhaps VS even has a setting to choose the legacy encoding.